# Why doesn't a diode pass current when reverse biased?

Tags: diodes, semiconductors

If one tacks a P-type semiconductor to an N-type semiconductor, a P-N junction forms in which electrons diffuse from the N-type to the P-type causing a diffusion current. Some time passes, and an electric field in the junction appears causing a drift current. At equilibrium, the diffusion current equals the drift current, hence a resultant of zero current is established.

Since in the forward biased mode, the built in electric field is weakened allowing more more diffusion current, I would expect that in the reverse biased mode more drift current should pass, but this is not the case. Why?

In this discussion, I am assuming no avalanche breakdown has yet occurred.

Another question I would like to ask at this point is that, if in the unbiased P-N junction, the depletion layer is depleted of any mobile charges, where does the drift current come from?

Comment: Diodes have leakage, so ‘some’ reverse current can flow. Normally more when it gets hot.

Comment: It can be confusing depending on what you assume is flowing, electrons or holes. In reverse bias the depletion layer widens and there is less current flow. Here is a basic reference for the operation of a PN diode.  https://energyeducation.ca/encyclopedia/Diode_operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would expect that in the reverse biased mode more drift current should pass, but this is not the case. Why?

In the reverse biased mode, drift current across the junction *would* be higher, but it is limited by the rate at which minority carriers travel from the metal electrodes to the PN junction. In a diode there are few of the minority carriers. Hence the drift current is low. (It does exist however). However, in a transistor, many minority carriers are injected into the base from the emitter, and easily cross the base-collector junction whether it is forward or reverse biased.

> Another question I would like to ask at this point is that, if in the unbiased P-N junction, the depletion layer is depleted of any mobile charges, where does the drift current come from?

In an unbiased PN junction, there is a greater concentration of holes in P-type quasi-neutral region, and a greater concentration of mobile electrons in the N-type quasi-neutral region. **Diffusion** causes holes to migrate to the N side of the junction and mobile electrons to migrate to the P side. This sets up an electric field. The electric field causes some of the holes to drift back to the P side and some of the mobile electrons to drift back to the N side.